# unpivot a dataframe with many columns into one with only 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

If I have a Dataframe which looks like:

```
clientid     CLNT1  CLNT2   CLNT3 CLNT4  ...  CLNTN
tradedate                                ...                                   
2019-07-01     0.0    0.0     0.0   0.0  ...   12.0
2019-07-02     0.0    0.0     0.0   0.0  ...    0.0
2019-07-03     0.0    0.0     0.0   0.0  ...    0.0
2019-07-05     0.0    0.0     0.0   0.0  ...    0.0
2019-07-08     0.0    0.0     0.0   0.0  ...    0.0
...            ...    ...     ...   ...  ...    ...
2020-01-31     0.0    0.0     0.0   0.0  ...    0.0
2020-02-03     0.0    0.0     0.0   0.0  ...    0.0
2020-02-04     0.0    0.0     0.0   0.0  ...    0.0
2020-02-05     0.0    0.0     0.0   0.0  ...    0.0
2020-02-06     0.0    0.0     0.0   0.0  ...    0.0
```

How can I collapse it into something like:

```
          clientid  count
tradedate    
2019-07-01   CLNT1    0.0
2019-07-01   CLNT2    0.0
2019-07-01   CLNT3    0.0
2019-07-01   CLNT4    0.0
...          ...      ...
2019-07-01   CLNTN   12.0
```

Apologies if this has been answered already. Rather new to pandas...

Comment: `df.stack().reset_index()`

Comment: or `melt`: `df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='tradedate', var_name='clientid', value_name='count')`

Comment: stack() seems to have done the trick I think. also, it is aptly named :) thank you very much